# PHP - Strip Tags allow "<3" text hearts

Tags: php, validation, strip-tags

Hey Guys, I usually come to StackOverflow for my php coding answers, although this time I could not seem to find one.

I am creating a social networking type website that requires lots of text entering and data checking. Everything seems good and the other day I was testing some characters users may enter and its seems that if I try to insert a '<3' it says its empty.

```
<?php
$text = "<3";
$clean = strip_tags($text);
echo $clean; // prints out nothing..
?>
```

Comment: HTML requires certain characters to be escaped: `<` becomes `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;`, and `&` becomes `&amp;`. If you use `&lt;3` it will be preserved.

Comment: Have you thought of doing escaping (`htmlspecialchars`) instead of filtering (`strip_tags`)?

Comment: I don't get why you would use `strip_tags`. If a user types in "<img>" they want the characters "<img>" to show up.

Comment: Not an answer, per se, so I'll just leave this as a comment. It seems like your use case supports a strategy like `[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)` rather than `strip_tags`. Chances are you just want to have the user's comment spat out as it appears in the text box. If I write "<" on Facebook, I'd like for "<" to show up on the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use htmlspecialchars instead strip_tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I did that function and then did the strip_tags after and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

"<3" will be break your HTML when you output it directly.

May you replace it with an (Heart)Image or other HTML- Tag( with css heart property) , like you would do with Smileys.